# Group an RDD by key in java

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to group an RDD by using groupby. Most of the docs suggest not to use groupBy because of how it works internally to group keys. Is there another way to achieve that. I cannot use reducebyKey because I am not doing a reduction operation here.

Ex-

```
Entry - long id, string name;
JavaRDD<Entry> entries = rdd.groupBy(Entry::getId)
                            .flatmap(x -> someOp(x))
                            .values()
                            .filter()
```

Answer (score 1):

[aggregateByKey [Pair]](http://homepage.cs.latrobe.edu.au/zhe/ZhenHeSparkRDDAPIExamples.html#aggregate) [see](https://dzone.com/articles/spark-pairrddfunctions-aggregatebykey)

Works like the aggregate function except the aggregation is applied to the values with the same key. Also unlike the aggregate function the initial value is not applied to the second reduce.

> ***Listing Variants***
>
> def **aggregateByKey**[U](zeroValue: U)(seqOp: (U, V) ⇒ U, combOp: (U, U)
> ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[(K, U)]
>
> def **aggregateByKey**[U](zeroValue: U, numPartitions: Int)(seqOp: (U, V) ⇒ U,
> combOp: (U, U) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[(K, U)]
>
> def **aggregateByKey**[U](zeroValue: U, partitioner: Partitioner)(seqOp: (U,
> V) ⇒ U, combOp: (U, U) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[(K, U)]

Example :

```
val pairRDD = sc.parallelize(List( ("cat",2), ("cat", 5), ("mouse", 4),("cat", 12), ("dog", 12), ("mouse", 2)), 2)

// lets have a look at what is in the partitions
def myfunc(index: Int, iter: Iterator[(String, Int)]) : Iterator[String] = {
  iter.map(x => "[partID:" +  index + ", val: " + x + "]")
}
pairRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(myfunc).collect

res2: Array[String] = Array([partID:0, val: (cat,2)], [partID:0, val: (cat,5)], [partID:0, val: (mouse,4)], [partID:1, val: (cat,12)], [partID:1, val: (dog,12)], [partID:1, val: (mouse,2)])

pairRDD.aggregateByKey(0)(math.max(_, _), _ + _).collect
res3: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((dog,12), (cat,17), (mouse,6))

pairRDD.aggregateByKey(100)(math.max(_, _), _ + _).collect
res4: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((dog,100), (cat,200), (mouse,200))
```

Comment: yes, your soultion will work if its a pair RDD. I had to first do byKey() operation to first convert it into a pair RDD

Comment: Yes you have to do a keyBy() first to proceed with above approach